# In what order is the ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() called in a view hierarchy?

Tags: android, layout

Is there a particular order in which the ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() called in a view hierarchy?

I'm trying to ensure that when ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() is called for a parent view, the same has been called for all its children view and thus their width and height has been calculated as well.

**P.S Please cite your source as well.**

Comment: see `ViewRootImpl` where `dispatchOnGlobalLayout` is called